# Consuming web services with jboss

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jax-ws, jax-rpc

Can someone point me a good step-by-step tutorial to consuming an already running web service in java?

PS: I tried creating the classes with `wsconsume`, but it cries with
`[ERROR] rpc/encoded wsdls are not supported in JAXWS 2.0.`  (my web service is rpc/encoded)

If I can consume web services entirely by hand (using no wizards), and understand how is it working, then I'll be happy.

Thanks!

**Update**: I have found out that rpc web services are not consumed using `jbossws`, but `jboss-jaxrpc`, which implements the JAX-RPC specification. I've found a guide for JAX-RPC [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-jaxrpc1/), but I'm still looking for other guides that could help.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) is the easiest way to get webservices running. Specifically look at the [Simple Frontend](http://cwiki.apache.org/CXF20DOC/simple-frontend.html). The simple front end uses reflection to convert the method/data types to a webservice. It doesn't get much easier than that.

CXF is pretty stable, but does not include all the WS specifications (WS-Eventing for example).

Answer (score 1):

How about the [JBossWS](http://jbossws.jboss.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=JBossWS) website? The details on the [client side wsconsume tool](http://jbossws.jboss.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=JBossWS_JAX-WS_Tools#Client_Side)  are probally what you will look at first.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the WSDL and XSD files, you can use the [Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/) web-services library to create Java classes that will interact with the services they describe.  From the stand-point of this library, you are creating a client application.

Comment: It's what I was doing (generated by the Eclipse wizard), but "the bosses" want to drop axis and use jbossws. :( Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can also consume web services with [Spring WS](http://static.springframework.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/client.html).